# How to move Sprite randomly on scene in AndEngine for example like mosquito movement

Tags: sprite, move, andengine

I'm developing an AndEngine game in which I want to move the Sprite randomly on scene like mosquito movement. Its a simple sprite and not a physics body.

Comment: I did it using physic body

Comment: What have you achieved so far?